# Why isn't the result of the inverse matrix function showing up?

Tags: vba

I've the following function for getting the inverse matrix from a range of numbers (matrix) on spreadsheet 1, but I'm getting an error.

```
Dim num As Integer
Dim instance As WorksheetFunction

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value = instance.MInverse(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Value)

MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm getting an error" is a pretty poor problem description, but what's the `.Value` of `Range("A1:B2")`? What *type* of parameter(s) is `instance.MInverse` expecting? If it's a single value, then the address string should span 1 cell. If it's multiple cells, remove `.Value` and pass it the `Range` object.

Comment: The error that I'm getting is: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

`.Value` of `Range("A1:B2")` is a range of cells that contain integer numbers.

`instance.MInverse` is expecting an array, so I though that passing a range of cells would do the trick.

Comment: `instance` is not actually instantiated. It is a variable which is equal to `Nothing` since you haven't set it equal to anything. I don't see any point in declaring something to be `WorksheetFunction` variable anyway, since the *only* thing you can assign to it is `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: Please note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide, such as the error message, please update your question by clicking on the **[edit]** link under the post. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnColeman

Thanks for the reply! After reading your comment, I noticed what I was missing in the code and everything worked fine after that.

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:B7").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Value)`
    
`MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value`

Answer (score 1):

This excerp is taken from [CPearson: Introduction To Array Formulas](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx).

Note: as the Excel Minverse function returns an array of values, the function must be entered as an Array Formula. To input an array formula, you need to first highlight the range of cells for the function result. Type the function into the first cell of the range, and press CTRL-SHIFT-Enter.